# html loading iframe content as last

Tags: html, iframe

For a client I have to make a website that will be put in an iframe.
They wan't me that I load the images async to reduce the load on their page.

My first question is, won't a browser load the content of the iframes as last after all the other content is loaded?

Second, instead of me detecting if the iframe is visible by the user, and then load the images my website has, doesn't it make more sense that they detect when the iframe is visible, and if so load the content of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to load it after the page was build

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/